# PHP insert HTML form values notice array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have a notice when I'm try to insert form values to database:

`Array to string conversion in C:\path\rangking.inc.php on line 41`

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167432/php-pdo-insert-using-loop/14167510#14167510) but I have a different array that showing with `print_r` is:

`Array ( [ia] => 6 [ik] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) [nn] => Array ( [0] => 80 [1] => 79 [2] => 79 [3] => 80 ) ) 1`

any suggesting answer would be appreciate

form HTML :

```
    if($_POST){

    include_once 'includes/rangking.inc.php';
    $eks = new rangking($db);

    $eks->ia = $_POST['ia'];
    $eks->ik = $_POST['ik'];
    $eks->nn = $_POST['nn'];

    if($eks->insert2()){
?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Berhasil Tambah Data!</strong> Tambah lagi atau <a href="rangking.php">lihat semua data</a>.
</div>
<?php
    }

    else{
?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Gagal Tambah Data!</strong> Terjadi kesalahan, coba lagi.
</div>
<?php
    }
    }
?>
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ia">Alternatif</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="ia" name="ia">
        <?php
            $stmt3 = $pgn1->readAll();
            while ($row3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                extract($row3);
                echo "<option value='{$id_alternatif}'>{$nama_alternatif}</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <?php
            $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
            while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                extract($row2);
        ?>
        <label for="ik"><?php echo $nama_kriteria; ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik[]" id="ik" value=<?php echo $id_kriteria ?>>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nn" name="nn[]">
        <?php
            }
        ?>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="location.href='rangking.php'" class="btn btn-success">Kembali</button>
</form>
<?php (print_r($_POST)); ?>
```

code of `rangking.inc.php` :

```
    function insert2(){

        $query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','')";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->ia);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->ik);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->nn);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

***EDIT***

`mixing function code of _chris85_ and mine` :

```
$query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','')";
foreach ($this->ik as $key => $value){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->ia);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->nn[$key]);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to insert the values of HTML form into database, but on HTML form, i'm using some loop in `ik and nn` to show each values from database to tag with `<label>`,actually i've an error in line 41 and 42, line 41 is `$stmt->bindParam(2, $this->ik);`

Comment: I've made an example answer below, give that a try. If it works please accept, if not please enable error reporting (I didn't test), and/or comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `nn` and `ik` are arrays you need to loop over them and bind each value. Here's a rough example of how you could do that assuming `nn` and `ik` have a one to one relationship.

```
$query = "insert into ".$this->table_name. " values";
error_log('IK' . print_r($this->ik, 1));
foreach($this->ik as $key => $value) {
     error_log('In Loop');
     $query_bits[] = '(?, ?, ?, "", "")';
     $params[] = $this->ia;
     $params[] = $value;
     $params[] = $this->nn[$key];
}
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query . implode(',' $query_bits));
$stmt->execute($params);
```

This is a rough, untested sample of how it should work.

Don't put variables into `$query_bits` or you will loose the purpose of preparing/binding.

This approach is making on large `insert` statement with each row's data separated by a comma.

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas.

-https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: i don't know about how `$query_bits` working? also on line 1 you forgot to add `;` at the end of line,

Comment: `$query_bits` is an array of the data each row will contain. This is one large insert now. ( I figured there'd be a typo somewhere, corrected). I've added the `mysql` manual reference as well.

Comment: when i tried your code above, i've got an error `syntax error, unexpected '$query_bits' (T_VARIABLE) on line 8` that's mean i need to create a new variable called `$query_bits` first?

Comment: That sounds like it didn't enter the `foreach`. Is `$this->ik` populated?

Comment: yes i though, because i can use my function last time for `<select>`

Comment: Okay, can you use the updated code and check your error logs after a form re-submit? If you don't have access to the error logs change the `error_log(..)` to `echo `.

Comment: nothing show except `syntax error, unexpected '$query_bits' (T_VARIABLE) on line 10` whatever i used `error_log` nor `echo`, im actually confused, but i've tried mix your code with my code, and it's just insert first values, :( _i've edited my mixing code of yours_

Comment: @dreq That is not my code, your `return` will stop the writing of any additional rows. Do the `prepare` and `execute` outside the `foreach` and use 1 query.

Comment: i just add `foreach($this->ik as $key => $value)` and change `$this->ik and $this->nn` to your code on line 7 and 8 `$value and $this->nn[$key]`, actually i'm not familiar with PHP, maybe the problem is about my array `ia` because it just had 1 array?

Comment: `<select class="form-control" id="ia" name="ia">` is not an array, is that your actual code? Did you follow what I said about the `return`? That will only allow 1 row, because you then return.

Comment: _update_, now my database can stored the values of array when i deleted about `return` of mixing code as you said (accepted post as an answer), but the warning about `if($eks->insert2())` running `else` statement, how do i can fix it? do you have an idea or should i ask a new question?

Comment: there's no error showing, just when i'm click the button, the code running `else (line 19)` in `if($_POST)` of HTML code, even though my values can insert to mysql

Comment: Oh, because you removed the `return` so it returns nothing and is consider false. Check for failure on each insertion, if it fails return false. After the looping return true, because it must not have failed. (...or use the approach I have then it will only need to check once, prepare once, and execute once)

Comment: why it's too complex, -_- , i can't imagine about your comment, i'm so silly maybe

Comment: It is more requests to your database than need to be made.

Comment: hahaha, yes i know that, i just think there's some way to _avoid_ it.

Comment: The approach here would only have 1 query.